# How to get a count after doing a Linq.Groupby C#

Tags: c#, linq

How can I get the count of the items in linqGroups below.
I want to show it in a debug/trace statement. 
The code is used to allow me to create one Purchase Order per vendor. So the question is how many vendor or Purchase Orders are there after running the .GroupBy clause.

```
    List<webPOInfo> lstPOInfo = new List<webPOInfo>();

    int poItemsCount = 0; 
    foreach (var item in linqQuery)
    {
        poItemsCount++; 
        webPOInfo info = new webPOInfo(item.qVendorName, item.qSku, item.qTransID, item.qSize, item.qQty);
        lstPOInfo.Add(info);
    }


    //loop through each vendor name group
    var linqGroups = lstPOInfo.GroupBy(x => x.VendorName);

    int countLinkGroups = linqGroups.Count<webPOInfo>;  // Error here
```

My attempt above gives me "Error    1   Cannot convert method group 'Count' to non-delegate type 'int'. Did you intend to invoke the method?"

Comment: The error message is telling you what's wrong: **did you intend to invoke the method?**  We invoke methods in C# by using the `method(arguments)` syntax. Can you say a little about why the error message was unclear? I design compiler error messages for a living and it is helpful to me to know how they can be improved.

Comment: I didn't know it was a method here, seems like usually its a property, and the Intellisense said count<> which through me off.

Comment: That's helpful, thanks. FYI there are no generic properties in C#; if you see `Something<T>` then `Something` must be either a type or a method. Also, the error message says both "method group Count" and "did you intend to invoke the method?" both are intended to be a strong hint to you that this is a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Count()` extension method directly for groups

```
var linqGroups = lstPOInfo.GroupBy(x => x.VendorName);

int countLinkGroups = linqGroups.Count();
```

That will give you the amount of vendors, hope this can help you

Comment: Okay, interesting that it's a method here, but usually a property.  Intellisense shows Count<>.  Instead of using "var linkGroups", what specific class could I put in place of "var"?

Answer (score 2):

Count is a method so your last line should look like this:

```
int countLinkGroups = linqGroups.Count();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1):

You perform the count on the grouping itself like

```
var linqGroups = lstPOInfo.GroupBy(x => x.VendorName)
 .Select(x => new { Key = x.key, 
                    Count = x.Count()
                  }).ToList();
```

Comment: Okay, so how do I get the count into a variable using this technique?